# onclick attribute not working with flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

So i am trying to create a simple side-nav with flexbox...
when the blue div.. is clicked I want the red div to change from a width "flex" of 0 to 1 which is "50%"....
my code is below but I will also include a codepen...

HTML

```
<div class="container flex">
<div class="blue" onclick="clickBlue();"></div>
<div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container{background:rgba(0,0,0,.1); width:100%; height:100px;}
.blue{background:rgba(0,0,250,.2); flex:1; height:100px;}
.red{background:rgba(250,0,0,.4); flex:1; height:100px;}
.flex{display:flex; justify-content:center; align-items:center;}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function clickBlue(){ 
$(".red").css("flex","1");
}
});
```

http://codepen.io/gebrutommy/pen/bwEGBv

Comment: Check your console, the function is undefined because the HTML is rendering before the JS is loaded.

Comment: Works fine if you put the function in the proper place https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/t757Lm6y/

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you are defining `clickBlue` inside on ready callback, hence its scope is not global, so you cannot reference it from the global scope. To solve this issue define the `clickBlue` in the global scope. without the `document.ready` function.

```js
function clickBlue() {
  $(".red").css("flex", "1");
}
```

```css
.container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}
.blue {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 250, .2);
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: rgba(250, 0, 0, .4);
  flex: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container flex">
  <div class="blue" onclick="clickBlue();"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. this solves your issue, but its better if you keep the document.ready callback and add a click listener on the `.blue` selector inside, without using html hooks.

```
$('.blue').on('click', clickBlue);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your clickBlue function is inside another function and therefore not accessible in the document. Try adding it via jQuery in the same scope. For example, right after you declare the function, try:

`$('.blue').on('click',clickBlue);`

And remove it from the "onclick" of the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your function clickBlue is undefined.

You can instead add an event listener to blue div like this:

**Code Snippet:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".blue").on("click", function() {
    $(".red").css("flex", "1");
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  height: 100px;
}
.blue {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 250, .2);
  flex: 1;
  height: 100px;
}
.red {
  background: rgba(250, 0, 0, .4);
  flex: 0;
  height: 100px;
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container flex">
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
</div>
```